# kotlin and papermc not calling a function

Tags: kotlin, minecraft

I am trying to create a plugin for papermc and i have a class in startgamecommand.kt under "commands" folder:

```
package me.veryg00dminecraftname.itemrun.commands

import org.bukkit.Bukkit
import org.bukkit.command.Command
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender
var numberofrounds=1
class startgamecommand : CommandExecutor {
    override fun onCommand(sender: CommandSender, command: Command, label: String, args: Array<out String>?): Boolean {

        for (i in 1..numberofrounds) {
            var itemtoobtain="someblock"
            var command ="fill 1 73 3 -4 76 -2 minecraft:air"
            Bukkit.dispatchCommand(Bukkit.getConsoleSender(), command)

        }
        return true
    }
}
```

and a function in "itemrun" called  "registerCommands" which executes it when the command is called. the function is called in "onEnable":

```kotlin
package me.veryg00dminecraftname.itemrun
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin
import me.veryg00dminecraftname.itemrun.commands.startgamecommand // Note the corrected import here

class Itemrun : JavaPlugin() {
    override fun onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic
        logger.info("hi console")

        registerCommands()
    }

    private fun registerCommands() {
        getCommand("start")?.setExecutor(startgamecommand()) // Pass an instance of StartGameCommand
        logger.info("registered commands")
    }

    override fun onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }
}
```

and here is the code in plugin.yml

```yaml
name: itamarsitemrun
version: '${project.version}'
main: me.veryg00dminecraftname.itemrun.Itemrun
api-version: '1.20'
commands:
  start:
    description: starts the game
```

When I reload the plugins ,the console only logs "hi console", and the command dosen't work.
the server log when reloading:

```
[15:13:52 INFO]: g00dname issued server command: /reload confirm
[15:13:52 INFO]: g00dname: Please note that this command is not supported and may cause issues when using some plugins.
[15:13:52 INFO\: g00dname: If you encounter any issues please use the /stop command to restart your server.
[15:13:52 INFO]: Using 4 threads for Netty based IO
[15:13:52 INFO]: Server Ping Player Sample Count: 12
[15:13:52 INFO]: Disabling itamarsitemrun v1.0-SNAPSHOT
[15:13:53 INFO]: Loaded 7 recipes
[15:13:53 INFO]: Loading server plugin itamarsitemrun v1.0-SNAPSHOT
[15:13:53 INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[15:13:53 INFO]: Enabling itamarsitemrun v1.0-SNAPSHOT
[15:13:53 INFO]: hi console
[15:13:53 INFO]: g00dname: Reload complete.
[15:13:53 INFO]: Timings Reset
```

Comment: As the command line indicates, `/reload confirm` is not an officially-supported API and is known to cause many problems. You should restart your server when you make plugin changes.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo i tried it and it didnt  help, thanks anyways

Comment: Can you show us your `onEnable` and `registerCommands` functions? I don't see anything wrong with the command implementation from here.

Comment: I accidently pasted the same code twice... here i updated the post

Comment: You should not use like `new startgamecommand()` ?